# Cache table values globally in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.4

I have a table: settings with the model `Setting`

```
class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'value',
    ];
}
```

I have created a service provide `SettingsServiceProvider` and registered in `app.php`

```
class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Factory $cache, Setting $settings)
    {
        if (\Schema::hasTable('settings')) {
            config()->set('settings', Setting::pluck('value', 'name')->all());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

After adding the `name` and `value` to the table `settings`, I am calling it in the view like this:

```
{{ config('settings.sitename') }}
```

Where `sitename` is the `name` field which returns the value perfectly.

**Problem:**
The problem with this method is that with every page request makes a DB call. And as these settings are not meant to be changed frequently, so I was looking for a method to cache it in the laravel cache.

I tried the following:

```
class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Factory $cache, Setting $settings)
    {
        $settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
        {
        return $settings->pluck('name', 'value')->all();
        });
        config()->set('settings', $settings);

        /* if (\Schema::hasTable('settings')) {
            config()->set('settings', Setting::pluck('value', 'name')->all());
        } */
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But when I try to return it to the view like this:

```
{{ config('settings.sitename') }}
```

nothing gets return.

Comment: As `remember` is a way of getting a value - with a default if it doesn't exist, it could be that a value already exists from earlier testing (for example).  It could be worth restarting the server (if possible) and see if it still happens.

Comment: I tried everything, it doesn't returns any value in the view.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the config cache `php artisan config:clear `

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I haven't tried it before, I tried it just now but still no value was returned to the view.

Comment: What do you get when you do `{{ dd(config('settings')) }}` ?

Comment: It returns an array with 8 elements, But the settings table has 12 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the post but this should solve it

Replace:

```
return $settings->pluck('name', 'value')->all();
```

With:

```
return $settings->pluck('value', 'name')->all();
```

and then with the usual:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt,
just type

```
php artisan
```

OR

```
 php artisan list
```

> It gives list of command with Explanation which help u lot

[image]

Thank you.